# Settings app broken

Tags: ios, gmail, settings, ipad

I use an iPad Air with iOS 7.0.3. Today I changed the notification settings of the GMail app.

After that, it's **not possible any more, to open the 'Settings' app.** I tap it and it closes immediately.

I restarted the iPad several times, closed all apps but nothing helps. Has anyone an idea what to do?

Comment: I just tried it again - 10 hours later - and now it works without doing anything :-)

Answer (score 3):

These are only suggestions, not definitive answers, but try the following:

1) Double tap home to enter the multitasking screen, and dismiss the settings app (flick it off the screen) - this app uses fast app switching to save state so next time it restarts, it restarts in the same area.  This can be persistent over a reboot.  Force quitting the app in this way should require it to restart from scratch and drop the saved state

2) Remove the Gmail app, it's possible that corrupt settings are making the settings app crash, and removal of the app may also result in removal of those settings

If none of these work, you are looking at a restore.

Comment: +1 for #1. That sounds like it will work. Alternatively, a **hard reset** might solve it. (lock button and home button held for 6+ seconds)

Comment: Yes, this is also worth trying as a step 3, I believe that a hard reset essentially drops all saved states for all apps and the OS to ensure the OS is booted to entirely default values without carrying over any states prior to reboot.